# Extracting table column values from html table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Only started using javascript 2 weeks ago so I only have a limited understanding.

I have some javascript code that generates a html table from excel documents and i need to extract the values from part of one column and place those values into an array. Which i later will use to generate a line graph. The code mainly needs to work on IE11.

Truncated example table below.

```
    <tbody>
       // several other rows here
        <tr>
            <td id="sjs-A16">column head A</td>
            <td id="sjs-B16">column head B</td>
            <td id="sjs-C16">column head C</td>
            <td id="sjs-D16">column head D</td>
            <td id="sjs-E16">column head E</td>
            <td id="sjs-F16">column head F</td>
            <td id="sjs-G16">column head G</td>
            <td id="sjs-H16">column head H</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="sjs-A17">1A</td>
            <td id="sjs-B17">1B</td>
            <td id="sjs-C17">1C</td>
            <td id="sjs-D17">1D</td>
            <td id="sjs-E17">1E</td>
            <td id="sjs-F17">1F</td>
            <td id="sjs-G17">1G</td>
            <td id="sjs-H17">1H</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="sjs-A18">2A</td>
            <td id="sjs-B18">2B</td>
            <td id="sjs-C18">2C</td>
            <td id="sjs-D18">2D</td>
            <td id="sjs-E18">2E</td>
            <td id="sjs-F18">2F</td>
            <td id="sjs-G18">2G</td>
            <td id="sjs-H18">2H</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="sjs-A19">3A</td>
            <td id="sjs-B19">3B</td>
            <td id="sjs-C19">3C</td>
            <td id="sjs-D19">3D</td>
            <td id="sjs-E19">3E</td>
            <td id="sjs-F19">3F</td>
            <td id="sjs-G19">3G</td>
            <td id="sjs-H19">3H</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
   //several more empty rows here
    </tbody>
```

I need the value of all cells with ids in the E(xx) but only id sjs-E17 and greater (sjs-Exx where xx >= 17), so value 1E-3E+ but no cell above that one (so not sjs-E16 to sjs-E1).

The number of rows i varies but the needed values always start on row 17. And as seen the scrip generates several empty rows after the values stop, but none of them have any id.

Expected results is just an array (or function) containing the values from cell E17+

```
 var test_array = ["1E", "2E", "3E", ...];
```

Comment: cannot really understand what you need. could you please include ***expected results*** considering your example above.

Comment: Edited to show expected results

Comment: you only want all values that contain `E` ? dude, include all your expected results, don't be lazy to use `...`. what the heck is `. . . ` ???

Comment: what is `only sjs-E17 and greater`, actually? how do you know that the id is greater than `sjs-E17`?

Comment: Greater as in higher, number E18 is higher than E17 and E19 is higher than E18. And i cannot include all expected result because the size of the table varies from as low as 1 <tr> to as many as 27 hence the use of en ellipsis (...)

Comment: and I know the id is greater than sjs-E17 because the E17 is from the excel file cell number, the sjs is from the converter.

Comment: so all id's that is `sjs-Exx` where `xx >= 17`?

Comment: yes, edited post for clarity

Comment: what if you have an id of `sjs-E19somealphabet`? will this be included? Or, are you sure that all id's will have numbers after `sjs-(letter)`

Comment: they will always be in the form of sjs-(letter)(number) for any size table that would possibly be used by the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `jQuery`, you can do this:

```js
var td = $('[id^="sjs-E"]'),
  valArray = [];
td.each(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id'),
    idVal = +id.substring(5); //parse value after `E` to number using (+)
  //check if idVal is number
  if (!isNaN(idVal)) {
    if (idVal >= 17) {
      valArray.push($(this).html());
    }
  }
});
console.log(valArray);
```

```css
.header {
  background-color: grey;
  font-size: 15px;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="header">
      <td id="sjs-A16">column head A</td>
      <td id="sjs-B16">column head B</td>
      <td id="sjs-C16">column head C</td>
      <td id="sjs-D16">column head D</td>
      <td id="sjs-E16">column head E</td>
      <td id="sjs-F16">column head F</td>
      <td id="sjs-G16">column head G</td>
      <td id="sjs-H16">column head H</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="sjs-A17">1A</td>
      <td id="sjs-B17">1B</td>
      <td id="sjs-C17">1C</td>
      <td id="sjs-D17">1D</td>
      <td id="sjs-E17">1E</td>
      <td id="sjs-F17">1F</td>
      <td id="sjs-G17">1G</td>
      <td id="sjs-H17">1H</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="sjs-A18">2A</td>
      <td id="sjs-B18">2B</td>
      <td id="sjs-C18">2C</td>
      <td id="sjs-D18">2D</td>
      <td id="sjs-E18">2E</td>
      <td id="sjs-F18">2F</td>
      <td id="sjs-G18">2G</td>
      <td id="sjs-H18">2H</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="sjs-A19">3A</td>
      <td id="sjs-B19">3B</td>
      <td id="sjs-C19">3C</td>
      <td id="sjs-D19">3D</td>
      <td id="sjs-E19">3E</td>
      <td id="sjs-F19">3F</td>
      <td id="sjs-G19">3G</td>
      <td id="sjs-H19">3H</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- several empty rows -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Or, using vanilla javascript:

```js
var tdRE = /^sjs-E([2-9]\d|1[7-9]|[1-9]{3,})$/,
  els = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
  valArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  var match = tdRE.exec(els[i].id);
  if (match) {
    if ((+match[1]) >= 17) { //the (+) operator again, convert string to number and check if >= 17
      valArray.push(els[i].innerHTML);
    }
  }
}
console.log(valArray);
```

```css
.header {
  background-color: grey;
  font-size: 15px;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="header">
      <td id="sjs-A16">column head A</td>
      <td id="sjs-B16">column head B</td>
      <td id="sjs-C16">column head C</td>
      <td id="sjs-D16">column head D</td>
      <td id="sjs-E16">column head E</td>
      <td id="sjs-F16">column head F</td>
      <td id="sjs-G16">column head G</td>
      <td id="sjs-H16">column head H</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="sjs-A17">1A</td>
      <td id="sjs-B17">1B</td>
      <td id="sjs-C17">1C</td>
      <td id="sjs-D17">1D</td>
      <td id="sjs-E17">1E</td>
      <td id="sjs-F17">1F</td>
      <td id="sjs-G17">1G</td>
      <td id="sjs-H17">1H</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="sjs-A18">2A</td>
      <td id="sjs-B18">2B</td>
      <td id="sjs-C18">2C</td>
      <td id="sjs-D18">2D</td>
      <td id="sjs-E18">2E</td>
      <td id="sjs-F18">2F</td>
      <td id="sjs-G18">2G</td>
      <td id="sjs-H18">2H</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="sjs-A19">3A</td>
      <td id="sjs-B19">3B</td>
      <td id="sjs-C19">3C</td>
      <td id="sjs-D19">3D</td>
      <td id="sjs-E19">3E</td>
      <td id="sjs-F19">3F</td>
      <td id="sjs-G19">3G</td>
      <td id="sjs-H19">3H</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- several empty rows -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

***Regex explanation:***
`^sjs-E([2-9]\d|[1-9][7-9]|\d{3,})$`

```
^ - asserts beginning of string
() - catching group
| - logical OR
$ - end of string

^sjs-E - starts with sjs-E
[2-9]\d - matches between 20 - 99
OR
1[7-9] - matches 17 - 19
OR
[1-9]{3,} - matches 100 and above
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let result = [];
$('table tr td[id^="sjs-E"]').each(function(){
  let ele = $(this);
  //extracting last two digits of id
  let digits = ele.attr('id').slice(-2);
  if(!isNaN(digits) && digits >= 17){
    result.push(ele.html());
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="sjs-A16">column head A</td>
            <td id="sjs-B16">column head B</td>
            <td id="sjs-C16">column head C</td>
            <td id="sjs-D16">column head D</td>
            <td id="sjs-E16">column head E</td>
            <td id="sjs-F16">column head F</td>
            <td id="sjs-G16">column head G</td>
            <td id="sjs-H16">column head H</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="sjs-A17">1A</td>
            <td id="sjs-B17">1B</td>
            <td id="sjs-C17">1C</td>
            <td id="sjs-D17">1D</td>
            <td id="sjs-E17">1E</td>
            <td id="sjs-F17">1F</td>
            <td id="sjs-G17">1G</td>
            <td id="sjs-H17">1H</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="sjs-A18">2A</td>
            <td id="sjs-B18">2B</td>
            <td id="sjs-C18">2C</td>
            <td id="sjs-D18">2D</td>
            <td id="sjs-E18">2E</td>
            <td id="sjs-F18">2F</td>
            <td id="sjs-G18">2G</td>
            <td id="sjs-H18">2H</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="sjs-A19">3A</td>
            <td id="sjs-B19">3B</td>
            <td id="sjs-C19">3C</td>
            <td id="sjs-D19">3D</td>
            <td id="sjs-E19">3E</td>
            <td id="sjs-F19">3F</td>
            <td id="sjs-G19">3G</td>
            <td id="sjs-H19">3H</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: no need for the `table tr td` selector since we are dealing with id's. also, `slice(-2)` will return `"01"` for `sjs-E101`, thus will be false for `digits >= 17`

Answer (score -1):

```
  var test_array = [];
  var isGreaterThan = 17;
  var until = 1000; // i don't know
  for (var i=isGreaterThan; i < until; i++) {
        var html = document.getElementById('sjs-E' + i.toString());
        if (html) {
               test_array.push(html.innerText);
        }
  }
```

Comment: it seems to work just the same if you use (i=17; i < 1000; i++) instead of the variables, am I missing something?

Comment: No, you're right! I used variables only if you want to check or do something before cycling documents...

Comment: this would work but quite inefficient. what if there are more than 1000 `sjs-E` ids? what if there's less than 10 `sjs-E` ids, would it be inefficient to loop 990 more?

Comment: mmm, I didn't think about it... You made your point. Looking at your answer I admit is better and also is not inefficient.